# Can I use a custom lifecycle defined in a multi-module project?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have a project that has a complex lifecycle, so a custom lifecycle makes sense.  However, I would like to be able to have the lifecycle defined in a plugin that is in the same multi-module build.  The plugin just defines the custom lifecycle (in a `components.xml`).

```
apollo-server-parent
  - apollo-server-lifecycle-plugin
    - src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml (defines apollo-server-product)
  - ApolloServer
    - pom.xml
```

`...
  <packaging>apollo-server-product</packaging>
...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>ca.nanometrics.apollo</groupId>
        <artifactId>apollo-server-lifecycle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>`

However, if I do this, maven won't build because it cannot find the apollo-server-lifecycle-plugin because it has not been built yet while building the reactor.  Any ideas on how to work around this?  Do I have to define the plugin in a separate project?

An example of the error I get:

```
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin ca.nanometrics.apollo:apollo-server-plugin:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact ca.nanometrics.apollo:apollo-server-plugin:jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT in releases (http://.../nexus/content/groups/public) @ 
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: apollo-server-product @ ca.nanometrics.apollo:ApolloServer:[unknown-version], /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/ApolloServer/pom.xml, line 10, column 14
     @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project ca.nanometrics.apollo:ApolloServer:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/ApolloServer/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin ca.nanometrics.apollo:apollo-server-plugin:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact ca.nanometrics.apollo:apollo-server-plugin:jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT in releases (http://.../nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: apollo-server-product @ ca.nanometrics.apollo:ApolloServer:[unknown-version], /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/ApolloServer/pom.xml, line 10, column 14
```

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] with sample POM files?

Comment: Using a plugin which is build in the same reactor does not work...

Comment: Typically, using a plugin within the same reactor _does_ work, but apparently not when you are using build extensions (eg custom lifecycles)

Comment: @Tunaki I edited the question with a bit more details, which I think is the MCVE required.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not getting you wrong here -

> You want to build `ApolloServer` module, which uses
>   `apollo-server-lifecycle-plugin` which is also a module of your
>   project.

Current project structure being :

```
apollo-server-parent
  - apollo-server-lifecycle-plugin
  - ApolloServer
```

---

From the [multi-module guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html), one simple way of doing this could be making sure that `apollo-server-lifecycle-plugin` is build prior to the `ApolloServer` module always. Easiest way to do that could be to include the dependency of `apollo-server-lifecycle-plugin` in `ApolloServer(pom.xml)` which would make sure the Reactor sorting builds plugin first.

> a plugin dependency on another module in the build